# How to have a floating/sticky window that pops up when you click it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net-mvc

Please take a look at: http://www.olark.com .

Do you see where it says "Leave us a Message" (Orange color box, bottom right side)? I am looking to do something exactly like that. I am developing in MVC so I would have to have a small box like that on the bottom of my page. When I click it, I will load a partial view content into that popped up box.

Does anyone know how I can achieve this? I tried to Google but I didn't have much luck because I don't even know what it's called (Floating Window? Sticky Window? Sticky Dialog?).

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CSS: with

```
#thisid
{
   position:fixed;
}
```

Or jQuery:

```
$(".thisid").onclick(function()
{
    popup and do magical stuff here
});
```

is one way to go, but chances are you want the box that pops up to do something like live chat or some other not so meneal assignment...in which case with your current understanding you will be best served by a third party plugin for chat...and the plugin will most likely position itself for you

Comment: You might also need a fallback for devices, as `position:fixed` is [not fully supported](http://bradfrostweb.com/blog/mobile/fixed-position/) as it allows users to become 'trapped'.

Comment: I just need it done with HTML/CSS/JQuery. I can handle the chat and stuff with SignalR, but the position is the biggest concern

Comment: well then feel free to click the big check mark and mark my answer correct please. Also, be more specific about what you just need in the future please

Comment: I showed you exactly what I wanted though. You saw a live example of what I wanted to do. Also, onclick did not work for me. I used click() instead. To have it on the bottom, i specified css: "bottom: 0". I guess this is the general idea, so it's completely upto the person how they want to customize it. Anyway, marked as correct answer. Thanks.